# Generation of employee id

Tags: ado.net

I have form empdetails like this

EmpId:textbox          Name:textbox
username:textbox       Password:textbox

I need to generate empid and it start with 0001 and display it in the empid field and all other information will be entered employee and i have provided save button when the user clicks on it it should be saved in the db and next time when the user clicks on this form it should display empid as 0002 and the process continues.When the user clicks on the save button it should be saved in the db and it should display in the gridview with id and name field made it as hyperlink.

Can any1 help me on this

With Regards,
Sweety

Answer (score 0):

If this is a single user application, you just have to make a max(id) sql to get the largest id and increase the number by one. Use a numberformatting class for the leading 0s.

If this is a multi user application (more than one user could open at the same time) you should create a new table which is made to automatically reserve the number for the time you are in this form. If you cancel the form, the number will be freed again and usable for the next opening. If you create a user, the state moves from open over reserved to used. This will prevent any doubleid errors.